# Keycloak logging to JSON format message field

Tags: json, kubernetes, jboss, wildfly, keycloak

I have been trying to set up keycloak logging to be scraped by fluentd to be used in elasticsearch. So far I have used the provided CLI string to use in my helm values script.

```
  cli:
    # Custom CLI script
    custom: |
      /subsystem=logging/json-formatter=json:add(exception-output-type=formatted, pretty-print=true, meta-data={label=value})
      /subsystem=logging/console-handler=CONSOLE:write-attribute(name=named-formatter, value=json)
```

[image: Keycloak logs]

However, as you can see in the picture provided, the logs that are generated seem to be completely json apart from the core of the log, the message field. Currently the message field is provided as comma separated key-value pairs. Is there any way to tell keycloak, jboss or wildfly that it needs to provide the message in JSON too? This allows me to efficiently search through the data in elastic.

Comment: It looks like the message is logged through a logger like that. There is no way to tear down a message like that in the `org.jboss.logmanager.formattesr.JsonFormatter`. One option would be to write a custom formatter or handler.

Comment: Is there a way to configure keycloak itself that it restructures the message before sending it to wildfly?

Comment: I don't know, but my assumption is no. That format is coming from a logger so if it's always gonna pass through a logger there's nothing that can be done short of writing a custom handler or formatter.

Comment: If you intent is to use Splunk or Elastic, you can easily transform this data by telling both platforms that the data within Message is of KV nature.

In Splunk this is usually done via `props.conf` or `transform.conf` while in Elastic this is usually done via LogStash before the data gets indexed into ES.

Answer (score 0):

Check this project on GitHub: [keycloak_jsonlog_eventlistener: Outputs Keycloak events as JSON into the server log.](https://github.com/kill9zombie/keycloak_jsonlog_eventlistener)

> ## Keycloak JSON Log Eventlistener
>
> Primarily written for the [Jboss Keycloak docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/keycloak), it will output Keycloak events as JSON into the keycloak server log.
>
> The idea is to parse logs once they get to [logstash](https://www.elastic.co/logstash) via [journalbeat](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/journalbeat/current/index.html).
>
> Tested with Keycloak version 8.0.1